# PhysicsJS on mobile devices: how to optimize for speed

Tags: 2d, physics, javascript, performance

I'm (physics n00b) developing a small animation (gamification) in a mobile HTML5 app (PhysicsJS, HTML5, Cordova, Ionic, JavaScript).

This animation is derived from [Basket of verlet constraints](http://wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS/#demo-5). This basket has to carry a lot more bodies (circles).

I'm experiencing performance problems, even on decent hardware (iOS and Android, the latter is worse). The bodies move like if they were in an aquarium. If I remove the basket, the performance is way better, but not yet satisfactory.

**How can this be optimized** in a sense that users don't have the feeling of watching a film in slow-motion?

Are there any **tweaks to control the engine** to do less calculation?

Am I using the appropriate physics engine or **are there alternatives with significant better performance**?

Remark: on my MacBook in Chrome, there is absolutely no performance problem and all movements are very smooth -> no aquarium.

Answer (score 1):

Theres the parameter maxIPF given to the Physics constructor, set that lower for a faster but less precise simulation.
But this may be a question more of whole program optimization, do some profiling.

Answer (score 0):

I've found following tweaks to gain performance on mobile devices:

- removed basket (too many bodies to calculate)
- don't render on each step (see code below)
- use `world.warp()` to scale time increments
- use a changed gravity factor
- call `world.pause()` and `world.unpause()` whenever appropriate (e.g. when canvas gets invisible due to a dialog covering it)

With following options the tweaks are set:

```
var options = {
    gravityFactor: 1,
    warp: 1,
    renderSteps: 1
};
if (ionic.Platform.isWebView()) {
    options = {
        gravityFactor: 2,
        warp: 5,
        renderSteps: 2
    };
}
```

**Don't render on each step**

```
// render on each step
var stepNo = 0;
world.on('step', function () {
    ++stepNo;
    if (stepNo % options.renderSteps === 0) {
        world.render();
    }
});
```

**use `world.warp()` to scale time increments**

```
world.warp(options.warp);
```

**use a changed gravity factor**

```
var GRAVITY = 0.0004; // standard gravity for PhysicsJS

var acceleration = Physics.behavior('constant-acceleration')
      .setAcceleration({x: 0, y: GRAVITY * options.gravityFactor});

world.add([acceleration]);
```

---

Please don't hesitate, share your experience and provide the solutions which work best for you!

Comment: Thanks for those tips. I have tried that but I am not seeing any performance improvements. Wondering if you have found anything else that might be helpful?
Also using Cordova. Performance degrades as I add more bodies to the world. I am using a PIXI renderer.